# airmonn-ng doesnt create monitor

Tags: network-monitoring, airmon-ng

I have Ubuntu 16.04 as a guest VM runnin on a windows host. I have a USB wifi connector plugged in and this is visible and working in my VM

Now, I'm trying to run the command "sudo airmon-ng start wifi0" where wifi0 is the name of my interface

Each time I do this, I get an error

```
> sudo airmon-ng start wifi0
> 
> Found 5 processes that could cause trouble. If airodump-ng,
> aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after a short period of time,
> you may want to run 'airmon-ng check kill'
> 
>    PID Name    962 NetworkManager    973 avahi-daemon   1002
> avahi-daemon   1517 wpa_supplicant   2389 dhclient
> 
> PHY   Interface   Driver      Chipset
> 
> phy1  wifi0       rtl8192cu   Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8192CU 802.11n
> WLAN Adapter cat: /sys/class/ieee80211/phy1/device/net/wifi0mon/type:
> No such file or directory
> 
> Newly created monitor mode interface wifi0mon is *NOT* in monitor
> mode. Removing non-monitor wifi0mon interface...
```

It creates an interface named "rename4" though which doesnt work anyways in wireshark

```
iwconfig
rename4   IEEE 802.11bgn  Mode:Monitor  Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

wifi0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Any idea how I can create an interface in Monitor mode? I'm very new to all this so this is quite bafling.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried running `airmon-ng check kill` like it's suggesting?

Comment: yep, it kills the network manager and other services but still no luck. I also killed the network service manually but didnt help

Comment: Alright. First, reboot the system to clear out everything. Then, run `airmon-ng check kill`, and after that `ifconfig wlan0 down`, then `iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor`, and finally `ifconfig wlan0 up`

Comment: Thanks, I did that and it enables my USB adapter into monitor mode. It doesn't create a new interface but I suppose that doesn't really matter.

Comment: If I post it as an answer, would you kindle mark as such?

Comment: Ofcourse, I'm not sure how to mark a comment as an answer though so I'll answer my own question with your comment in it.

Comment: I was asking *if I* were to convert it to an answer, would you mark as such. Sometimes OPs never get back, and the question lives on in the "unanswered" section, even though it is answered. I have now converted my comment to a better quality answer, so if you wouldn't mind, just tick the ✔ in the top left corner of my answer, and it will be marked as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, reboot the system to clear out everything.

Next, open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>) and run these commands:

```
airmon-ng check kill
ifconfig wlan0 down
iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

*Note that while this **does not** create a **new** interface, it still achieves the **desired effect**, by putting the **existing** `wlan0` interface into monitor mode.*